# "Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension and encountering an error message in the console: "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist." I'm having trouble understanding its cause and how to resolve it.

Here's the relevant code snippet from my content script:

service-worker.js

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener((details) => {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    message: "background_to_popup",
    data: details,
  })
  console.log(details); 
}, {
  urls: ['<all_urls>'],
  types: ['main_frame'],
});
```

I'm not sure what is causing this error and how to establish the connection correctly between the content script and the background script. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) chrome.webRequest cannot be used in a content script so you shouldn't load this file as a content script. It should be loaded in exactly one place indicated in `service_worker` in manifest.json 2) You need to [re-inject content scripts explicitly](/q/10994324) after reloading/installing the extension. 3) Your code uses chrome.runtime.sendMessage to communicate with the popup and not the content script. 4) To send a message to a content script from the background script or service worker you need to use chrome.tabs.sendMessage and not chrome.runtime.sendMessage. The tab id is details.tabId.

Answer (score 0):

You should always catch the rejected promises.